# what does MIME type for computer system means?

Tags: java, mime-types

My client gave me the following requirement. I am not able to understand what he means
He says:

> I'm looking for a Java application
>   that sets a mime-type for the user's
>   computer system.
>
> The application would be a very simple
>   app (probably a single .class file?),
>   which when run, sets this mime-type
>   for the user's computer system:
>
> application/adlm
>
> Thus, if I am using Firefox or IE, for
>   example, I can just check for the
>   presence of the "application/adlm"
>   mime-type. If present, your
>   application worked.
>
> Please provide some javascript or PHP
>   that can be used to detect the present
>   of a custom mime-type like this.
>
> Please use the latest version of Java.
>   I will test your application from the
>   Windows command line. Please do not
>   make it Windows-specific, though... it
>   would be ideal if I could use your
>   application on a Macintosh system,
>   too.
>
> Please note that I'm looking for a
>   desktop java application, NOT a .jsp
>   file (i.e., this needs to run from the
>   Windows desktop, not on a web server)

Comment: You may wish to reword your question (or I'll do it for you) so that it sounds like you're asking, instead of demanding a solution.

Comment: I think the OP was given those requirements and he is asking for help understanding them. I'll edit.

Comment: Eric, he's not asking us to write the app: he just wants some pointers to understand what he's been asked to do in the firs place.

Comment: Why don't you just ask your client what they mean?

Comment: @redtuna - Got it, now that it's reworded it makes a lot more sense

Comment: @Unknown (google), you have asked 10 questions on SO and gotten a number of answers.  Please take a moment to review those questions and accept the best answer for each question.

Answer (score 4):

This makes no sense at all, given what a [MIME-type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME_type) is. A MIME-type is used to identify the format of a file distributed on a network, such as over the Internet.

Comment: However, Windows has a mechanism to associate the MIME type of content received in IE with a program to view/execute that content.  See my answer.

Comment: True, but that has nothing to do with the question asked.

Comment: I'd question the legitimacy of this project's intended project. It looks like somebody would want to install a mime type handler on somebody's computer and then have arbitrary commands being ran when the user visits some web pages.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds to me like your client wants to be able to add or edit a filetype in the registry.  This means that when a file has a MIME-type of  *application/adlm*, it is opened with whatever application is associated with *application/adlm*.  This has more to do with system settings, I think.

You should verify with the client to make sure you know what they mean.

Answer (score 2):

Computers don't have mime-types; HTTP responses do. Maybe he wants a web server that sends a reply using that MIME-type? It's just a matter of sending the right headers.

Comment: Technically any MIME message has a MIME type.  Mime originated as a mechanism for encapsulating rich content inside an RFC822 email message.

Answer (score 2):

On Windows and with Internet Explorer, a program can be associated with a particular mime type.  So, if IE downloads content with that mime type, the registered program will be launched (subject to security layers).

For more information on how to implement this [consult this MDSN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms775148(VS.85).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I think they want you to be able to set the default application to open a file of the given mime-type.

I don't believe that this can be done in a cross-platform way -- you'll have to check the OS and do the appropriate thing.

Answer (score -3):

A mime type is a little thing that's stored with a file which tells the "computer system" what kind of file it is. This allows files not to have little silly extensions on the name. It's part of the UNIX specification.

Comment: Since when are MIME types stored with files in Unix?  I think you're a bit confused.

Comment: Something is... or am I thinking about on my mac

Comment: Perhaps you're thinking of the "resource fork"?  That's Mac specific, and rather a different concept from MIME types.